# Draw canvas rectange with animation

Tags: android, animation, canvas

I draw rectangle with canvas. I would like draw rectangle with wobble animation. Example:
I have drawn a gray rectangle, when i click on this rectangle it will draw red rectangle with animation. Code to draw rectangle is ready. I don't know how can i animate rectangle.

[image]
[image]

Comment: use ObjectAnimator/ValueAnimator

Comment: what should to animate?

Comment: hmm,  errr,  i beg your pardon?

Comment: Simple rectangle is object Area with coordinates. I draw this object with canvas. How can animate when is drawn? Are you understand my problem?

Comment: so you want to draw red rectangle with animation but you dont know what animation should look like?

Comment: No, I dont know how animate this rectangle. Beacouse I drawn this rectangle with canvas

Comment: you can use runnable.for example draw rectangle with color start at #05ff0000 and end in #ffff0000 (this will add fill color effect),so place while in run method and when rectangle filled color then break.